# Error "integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint" in Spring hsqldb

Tags: sql, spring, database-schema, hsqldb

I am new to databases and server-side programming and in fact, this is the first time I am doing it. My schema.sql in hsql is defined as:

```
DROP TABLE User IF EXISTS;
DROP TABLE Favor IF EXISTS;

CREATE TABLE User (
    userId BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    mobile BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (userId)
);

CREATE TABLE Favor (
    favorId BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL,
    favorName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    favorDesc VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    datePosted TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    compensation VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    dateExpiring TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    posterId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    acceptorId BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (favorId),
    FOREIGN KEY (posterId) REFERENCES User (userId),
    FOREIGN KEY (acceptorId) REFERENCES User (userId)
);
```

and my controllers (UserController.java and FavorController.java) look like:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(
            value="/api/users",
            method=RequestMethod.GET,
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<User>> getUsers() {
        Collection<User> users = userService.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<Collection<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            value="/api/users",
            method=RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(
            @RequestBody User user) {

        User savedUser = userService.create(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(savedUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }
}
```

Favor.java

```
@RestController
public class FavorController {

    @Autowired
    private FavorService favorService;

    @RequestMapping(//denotes this is where http requests should go
            value="/api/favors",
            method=RequestMethod.GET,
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Favor>> getFavors() {//responseentity-> converts it into JSON and inserts it into HTTP response body
        Collection<Favor> favors = favorService.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<Collection<Favor>>(favors, HttpStatus.OK);//status code of 200
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            value="/api/favors/{id}",
            method=RequestMethod.GET,
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Favor> getFavor(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        Favor favor = favorService.findOne(id);
        if (favor == null)
            return new ResponseEntity<Favor>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);//status code of 404
        return new ResponseEntity<Favor>(favor, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            value="/api/favors",
            method=RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Favor> createFavor(
            @RequestBody Favor favor) {

        Favor savedFavor = favorService.create(favor);
        return new ResponseEntity<Favor>(savedFavor, HttpStatus.CREATED); //status code of 201

    }   
}
```

When I run the springboot application and make a POST request to add a Favor, I get the following in the command prompt (where the service is running). I can't tell what this is. Can somebody help me?

```
2015-08-09 00:40:42.127  INFO 10092 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.

[Tomcat].[lo
calhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-08-09 00:40:42.127  INFO 10092 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.Dispat
cherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization starte
d
2015-08-09 00:40:42.161  INFO 10092 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.Dispat
cherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization comple
ted in 33 ms
2015-08-09 00:40:42.424  WARN 10092 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.Sq
lExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: -10, SQLState: 23502
2015-08-09 00:40:42.425 ERROR 10092 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.Sq
lExceptionHelper   : integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint;
SYS_CT_10105 table: FAVOR column: FAVORNAME
2015-08-09 00:40:42.438 ERROR 10092 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dis
patcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in contex
t with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is o
rg.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statem
ent; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.C
onstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constra
int; SYS_CT_10105 table: FAVOR column: FAVORNAME
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Table.enforceRowConstraints(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertRowSet(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(
ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAn
dExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(Abstr
actReturningDelegate.java:58)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(Abstrac
tEntityPersister.java:3032)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(Abstrac
tEntityPersister.java:3558)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(Enti
tyIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(Ac
tionQueue.java:197)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java
:181)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertActio
n(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrR
eplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(Ab
stractSaveEventListener.java:195)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGenera
tedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWit
hGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTran
sient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(De
faultPersistEventListener.java:149)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(De
faultPersistEventListener.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntit
yManagerImpl.java:1181)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEnti
tyManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.persist(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityMa
nagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.persist(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.s
ave(SimpleJpaRepository.java:433)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySup
port$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.jav
a:436)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySup
port$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:421)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySup
port$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySup
port$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java
:506)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.
proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.
invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.in
voke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterc
eptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPos
tProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetad
ataPostProcessor.java:122)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invok
e(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynami
cAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.save(Unknown Source)
        at favorite.ws.service.FavorServiceBean.create(FavorServiceBean.java:34)

        at favorite.ws.web.api.FavorController.createFavor(FavorController.java:
52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvok
e(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeF
orRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocabl
eHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingH
andlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingH
andlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapt
er.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Dispatch
erServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Dispatche
rServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Frame
workServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServ
let.java:869)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkSer
vlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:206)
        at favorite.ws.filters.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:2
2)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInterna
l(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterIntern
al(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:668)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpo
int.java:1521)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoin
t.java:1478)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskTh
read.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In my front-end on Sencha Touch:
FavorsModel.js

```
    Ext.define('FavorITe.model.FavorsModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: [
         'Ext.DateExtras'
    ],
    config: {
        idProperty: 'favorId',
        identifier: 'sequential',
        fields: [
            { name: 'favorId', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'favorName', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'favorDesc', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'datePosted', type: 'date' },
            { name: 'compensation', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'dateExpiring', type: 'date' }
        ],
        validations: [
            { type: 'presence', field: 'favorName', message: 'Favor\'s missing a name!' },
            { type: 'presence', field: 'favorDesc', message: 'Mind explaining the favor a little more?' },
            { type: 'presence', field: 'dateExpiring' }
        ],
    },

    checkDates: function (errors) {
        if (this.get('datePosted') > this.get('dateExpiring')) {
            errors.add(Ext.create('Ext.data.Error', {
                field  : 'dateExpiring', 
                message: 'Expiry date can\'t be before today\'s date!'
            }));
        }
    },

    validate: function () {
        var errors = this.callParent(arguments);
        this.checkDates(errors);
        console.log(errors);
        return errors;
    }
});
```

Controller where I am making the AJAX request:

```
    Ext.define('FavorITe.controller.RequestFavorForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            cancelFavorButton: 'button[action=cancelFavor]',
            submitFavorButton: 'button[action=submitFavor]',
            requestFavorForm: 'requestFavorForm'
        },
        control: {
            cancelFavorButton: {
                tap: 'cancelRequestFavorForm'
            },
            submitFavorButton: {
                tap: 'submitRequestFavorForm'
            }
        }
    },

    cancelRequestFavorForm: function() {
        Ext.getCmp('start').animateActiveItem(0, {type: 'flip'});
    },

    submitRequestFavorForm: function() {
        var requestFavorForm = this.getRequestFavorForm();
        var currentFavor = requestFavorForm.getRecord();
        var newValues = requestFavorForm.getValues();

        currentFavor.set('favorName', newValues.favorName);
        currentFavor.set('favorDesc', newValues.favorDesc);
        currentFavor.set('compensation', newValues.compensation);
        currentFavor.set('dateExpiring', newValues.dateExpiring);
        currentFavor.set('datePosted', new Date());

        var errors = currentFavor.validate();

        if (!errors.isValid()) {
            errors.each(function(item, index, length) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Wait!', errors.getByField(item.getField())[0].getMessage(), Ext.emptyFn);
            });
            currentFavor.reject();
            return;
        }

        var allFavorsStore = Ext.getStore('AllFavorsStore');
        console.log(currentFavor);
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/favors',
            method: 'POST',
            jsonData: currentFavor,
            success: function() {
                console.log("success");
            },
            failure: function() {
                console.log("wooops");
            }
        });
        allFavorsStore.sync();

        Ext.getCmp('start').animateActiveItem(0, {type: 'slide', direction: 'up'});
    },

    //called when the Application is launched, remove if not needed
    launch: function(app) {

    }
});
```

Comment: How are you sending the request? Can we see it? You are probably not setting a field that must be populated.

Comment: @ACV: Updated my post. Please see.

Comment: You need to check that your <form with id `requestFavorForm` has al fields populated and that their name corresponds to what you want to send. Make sure the <input name = "`favorName`" exists and has value

Comment: @ACV: In my AJAX request, I set jsonData to currentFavor.data instead of currentFavor and in the success function put allFavorsStore.add(currentFavor) and the UI seems to be getting updated fine now. I am no longer getting those nasty hsqldb errors on the server side as well. However, if I make a Postman GET request to my server, I still don't see anything saved on there. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: What are you expecting to save when you do a GET request? GET is for GETting data, not saving to DB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136185/integrity-constraint-violation-not-null-check-constraint)

Answer (score 0):

Is as the error says, you're not setting the value in your java object which maps to the column `favor.favorName`, and that column is `not null`, so you must give it a value.

The problem is probably in the code of `favorService.create(favor);`.