# integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint

Tags: java, swing, ms-access, ucanaccess

```
ResultSet rs;

PreparedStatement ps;

Connection con;

public Attribute() {


    try{

         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/programming/myassignment/Database1.accdb");
        System.out.println("Java is now connected to database");


    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


  try{

PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into table1(Attributes) values(?)");
                   pstmt.setString(1, textField.getText());
                   pstmt.executeUpdate();
                   pstmt.close();





            }catch (Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex);

            }

        }
    });
    btnAdd.setBounds(152, 203, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnAdd);
```

This code is connecting to database but whenever i insert an attribute, it gives the above mentioned error.

this database is being used by two classes. first class will insert the class name into the ClassName column, then i will click on Add attribute button to open the above mentioned class. when i insert attribute in this and press the "Add" button, it gives the following error:

net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.7 integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10359 table: TABLE1 column: CLASSNAME

Comment: the error msg is obvious to me. the classname column is getting a NULL

Comment: yeah but the class name column is not null. first i enter the class name, then i enter the attribute.
the class name column in the database is showing the class name. its not null

Comment: where is that shown my friend :p

Comment: I removed the `mysql` tag. Not sure what that is doing in here with ms-access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the table TABLE1 has a NOT NULL constraint on the column CLASSNAME.

It means, you cannot insert a new row into the table without value for the CLASSNAME column.

After inserting the CLASSNAME, you should be updating the same row with the Attributes.

Your current code tries to insert a new row with only Attributes, hence the constraint throws an error.

Your update statement should be as below.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("update table1 set Attributes = ? where CLASSNAME = ?");
pstmt.setString(1, textField.getText());
pstmt.setString(2, "Previously Inserted Classname");
```

Also, check if the table has any other constraints (including a unique primary key )

Comment: i get your point and its working. but i didnt get the "previously inserted classname" part.

Comment: what should i write here? the class name which i entered before?

Comment: @AhsonJunani yes, the classname you entered before.

Comment: and what if there is another class like this in which i have to insert a function? like i click on enter function button, this opens another class and then i insert my function there.

Comment: PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("update table1 set Functions = ? where Attributes = ? where CLASSNAME = ?");
      pstmt.setString(1, textField.getText());
     
      pstmt.setString(2, "Ahson");
               
                  pstmt.executeUpdate();
                  pstmt.close();

Comment: i am using this code, similar to one that you told me before. but its not working. It is giving me the error 
 unexpected token: WHERE

Comment: @AhsonJunani the Where clause should be used only once and every subsequent criteria should be appended with and.  Your query should be as below.

PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("update table1 set Functions = ? where Attributes = ? and CLASSNAME = ?");